# Javascript: не подхватывается в дочернем классе метод родительского класса

Tags: javascript, reactjs, классы, typescript, наследование

Есть родительский класс:

```
class SnippetBase extends React.Component<any, any> {
    // callback: нажата кнопка сворачивания/разворачивания блока
    handleCollapse = (event: any) => {
        ....
    }

    // функция для подготовки тэгов
    prepareTags = (keywords: string[]) => {
        ...
    }
}
```

и есть дочерний класс

```
class Snippet extends SnippetBase {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.handleCollapse} />
                {this.prepareTags(this.props.tags)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Так вот:

родительский метод `this.handleCollapse` дочерний класс видит и метод работает - все хорошо

а вот родительский метод `this.prepareTags` дочерний класс не видит (функция не определена, поэтому на код вызова браузер ругается, что это не функция)

> this.prepareTags is not a function

В чем может быть дело и как это можно исправить

Comment: Скорее всего `this` не тот. Напишите там `{console.log(this) || this.prepareTags(this.props.tags)}` и посмотрите что в консоли пишет

Comment: а this из родительского или дочернего методов?

Comment: Не понял, просто там где у вас написано `{this.prepareTags(this.props.tags)}` в `Snippet`-е напишите то что я попросил и посмотрите что в консоли будет

Comment: проверил - `this` относится к дочернему классу и оба метода присутствую

Comment: Это странно, возможно в консоли отображается с опозданием, потому видны методы, давайте проверим так `console.log(prepareTags in this)`

Comment: вроде помогло следующее: в методе `render()` я написал `const prepareTags = this.prepareTags; .... <>{prepareTags(...)}</div>` и ошибки не было - может из самого метода все родительские методы видны, а вот уже из `<div>` видны только локальные переменные? просто внутрь `div` я `console.log` не могу вставить, чтобы проверить

Comment: Как это не можете? Я же только что показал как можно это сделать, в первом комментарии))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138064/discussion-between-zhihar-and-eziomercer).